# Visual Studio C++ Debugger: Can I escape the module name in a qualified type name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a type that is only defined inside one DLL (lets call it "foo.dll"), and not visible to any other DLLs. When I want to look at an instance of that type in a debugging context that is not inside the defining DLL, the Visual Studio debugger usually cannot display it because it does not know the type. That can be solved by qualifying the typename with the modulename, e.g. `(foo.dll!MyInternalType*) myOutsidePtr`. But if the DLL has the '.' character in its name, this does not work, e.g. `(foo.3.5.dll!MyInternalType*) myOutsidePtr` fails with "identifier foo is undefined". It seems like the debugger just cuts off at the first '.', probably to remove the ".dll" extension.

Visual Studio also offers the context operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/context-operator-cpp), which should might not have the '.' issue, but apparently cannot be used to qualify types, and I think it would change the context to the module anyway, so it wouldn't be possible to use it to resolve e.g. local variables in other modules.

Is there any way to escape the module name in `(foo.3.5.dll!MyInternalType*) myOutsidePtr` to make this work? Or is there any other workaround that does not involve changing the DLL filename?

EDIT:
In case my description was not clear enough, here is an example project: https://github.com/mooware/vs-watchexpr-example

[image: vs watch expression showing the issue]

In this screenshot, I cannot see the members of `ptr1` and `ptr2` in `main()` because their type definitions are internal to their libraries. As described, I can tell the debugger where to find the type with the context expression, here `watchexpr-lib!InternalStruct`, but that does not work for the other library, seemingly because of the '.' characters in the name.

Again, my question is: Can I write this watch expression in a way that makes it work? I would have hoped that there is some way of escaping or quoting the library name.

EDIT 2: Reported it as a bug in Visual Studio: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-Watch-Expressions:-Cannot-use-contex/10294144

Comment: Could you please provide steps and sample dll to reproduce the problem? It would be nice if there are pictures to describe the problem you are having, it will help everyone to understand your problem.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT I added an example project